# Create a bag with multiples topics

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'am newbie in ROS. In fact, I have a folder containing images, a file containing IMU data with its timestamps correspondence. How can i put all of them into a bag with multiples topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269206/create-a-bag-with-multiples-topics/) by [trinamntn08](https://answers.ros.org/users/30882/trinamntn08/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [rosbag Python API example](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#py_api).

That writes two msg types to two different topics (`chatter` and `numbers`).

Just make sure to use the correct message types (from [sensor_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/sensor_msgs): `sensor_msgs/Imu` and `sensor_msgs/Image`), and that, depending on whether the nodes that will be receiving these messages need it, to embed a `CameraInfo` topic with the intrinsics of the camera that was used as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0